# Bokeh and ipywidget interaction gives error with push_notebook() function

Tags: python, widget, ipython, bokeh, jupyter

I am following the example on [this](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.10.0/docs/user_guide/notebook.html) page, in which I try to create an interactive interface with IPython widgets and Bokeh.

When I run the interact code right at the bottom, I get the following error:

```
Javascript error adding output!
TypeError: ds is undefined
See your browser Javascript console for more details.
```

The `push_notebook()` function looks like it's the culprit. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Can you come by the GH issue tracker and provide more information? A copy of the notebook you are using would be the most helpful. Alternatively, an actual notebook you can try (as opposed to a screen shot which perhaps needs updating) is here: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/plotting/notebook/interact_basic.ipynb

Comment: @bigreddot I'm happy to do so! :-) FWIW, I was following the example on the Bokeh page exactly. And I just posted an issue on the Bokeh Github repository!

Comment: Thanks! we will be able to run things down there